Python flink job with Docker
Can anyone show me a way to use a simple Python flink job by using docker-compose?
I can run such a job but, I do not see anything on the FLink UI. But in the docker logs, I know the job has run successfully.
I am only able to access the localhost:8081 because jobmanager and taskmanager are running. But the python job which has completed is not visible on the completed jobs section on the Flink UI.
Here is the simple python code
from pyflink.datastream import StreamExecutionEnvironment
from pyflink.common.typeinfo import Types
from pyflink.datastream.functions import MapFunction

class Splitter(MapFunction):
    def map(self, value):
        return value.split()

def word_count():
    env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.get_execution_environment()

    # Create a DataStream with sample sentences
    text = env.from_collection([
        'hello world',
        'hello flink',
        'flink is fun'
    ])

    # Apply transformations to count words
    word_stream = text.map(Splitter(), output_type=Types.STRING()) \
                      .flat_map(lambda words: [(word, 1) for word in words], output_type=Types.TUPLE([Types.STRING(), Types.INT()])) \
                      .key_by(lambda x: x[0]) \
                      .sum(1)

    word_stream.print()

    env.execute('word_count_job')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    word_count()


this is the Dockerfile
# Base image for Flink
FROM apache/flink:1.18.0-scala_2.12

# Install Python 3.10 and pip
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3.10 python3-pip

# Set Python 3.10 as the default for `python` and `pip`
RUN update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python python /usr/bin/python3.10 1 \
    && update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/pip pip /usr/bin/pip3 1

# Install PyFlink
RUN pip install apache-flink==1.18.0

# Set working directory
WORKDIR /opt/flink/python_job

# Copy the Python Flink job script into the container
COPY word_count.py /opt/flink/python_job/

# Set the entry point to submit the job to the Flink cluster using the Flink CLI
# ENTRYPOINT [ "flink", "run", "-m", "jobmanager:8081", "/opt/flink/python_job/word_count.py" ]
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "/opt/flink/python_job/word_count.py" ]


Here is the docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'
services:
  jobmanager:
    build:
        context: .
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: flink:1.18
    container_name: jobmanager
    hostname: jobmanager
    networks:
      - flink-network
    ports:
      - "8081:8081"  # Flink UI
      # - "6123:6123"  # RPC Port
    expose:
      - "6123"
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    command: jobmanager

  taskmanager:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: flink:1.18
    container_name: taskmanager
    hostname: taskmanager
    # expose:
    #   - "6121"
    #   - "6122"
    networks:
      - flink-network
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
    links:
      - jobmanager:jobmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
      - TASK_MANAGER_NUMBER_OF_TASK_SLOTS=5
    command: taskmanager


  pyflink-job:
    build:
      context: .  # Path to your Dockerfile
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: pyflink-job
    hostname: pyflink-job
    networks:
      - flink-network
    depends_on:
      - jobmanager
      - taskmanager
    environment:
      - JOB_MANAGER_RPC_ADDRESS=jobmanager
    # entrypoint: flink run -m jobmanager:8081 /opt/flink/python_job/word_count.py

networks:
  flink-network:
    driver: bridge


Please help me how to see the completed job on flink UI, what I can guess is python job is not getting linked with job manager, it is running as a standalone process.
Please let me know what changes can I make here?

So ,you have problem in the Flink UI , not in the  Gcp datastream .

Yes. On flink UI not able to see the job in running and completed section.
